# Internationalization Fileupload Component (C# + ASP 4.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, internationalization, .net-4.5

I have the job to internationalize an entire website in C# and ASP.NET 4.5, but I can't find a way to make the Fuleupload to work with Resources. I've tried some things, like force the Culture the user selected (see below), but without success.

```
    <%@ Page Title="Chamado" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/principal.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false"
CodeBehind="ChamadoAbertura.aspx.cs" Inherits="ChamadoAbertura" UICulture="es-ES" Culture="en-ES" %>
```

I remember that I read someplace that is impossible, but if it REALLY is impossible I need **evidence** to show to my Boss that I can't do it, or I'm screwed.

I am really desperate here, I don't have good knowledge of ASP.NET. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try setting on the `Page_Load` event the following lines : 
`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture="es-ES";`
`System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture="es-ES";`
Also, did you make a typo at the `Culture="en-ES"` when posting your question, or is it like that in the code as well?

Comment: Are you dynamically changing the `Culture` or `UICulture` or relying on ASP.NET engine to recognise it based on browser?

Comment: Another thing , your UICulture is simply language , setting language-culture , not sure if that works, correct me if wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the long time to answer, long day and I was really tired to turn on my PC at home.

Alex, that was a typo in the code, but fixing that don't solved the problem, as your code suggestion.